# Labels with icons don't fit scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm adding labels with icons to a VBox inside a scrollPane.
My problem is using this method the contents doesn't fit scroll pane even if i fix height ( i have the impression that it has been overrided)

```
Sphere sphere = new Sphere(10);
Label l = new Label(s,sphere);
vbox.getChildren().add(l);
scrollpane.setContent(vbox);
```

Using labes without icons fit correctly to the scrollpane ..

How can i fix this problem?

Edit: 
[image: Vbox doesn't fit Scrollpane]

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have tried otherwise we are not able to tell what is wrong.

Comment: i paste the code i tried

Comment: What you have posted works as expected. Please post everything you have and please clarify what do you mean with "contents doesn't fit scroll pane even if i fix height".

Comment: i just edit the post with a screenshot. It looks like vbox doesn't fit scrollpane (inside of it ) it get by passed

Comment: Okay, I could reproduce it with `Shape`. If it is not crucial to have a `Sphere`, you could try it with another graphic, like `Label l = new Label("Text"+i, new Circle(8,Color.RED));`. I just tried it it displayed properly.

Comment: thanks :) it works perfectly